# How to enumerate all Miller indices in the unit cell?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

Taking the unit cell of $\rm NaCl$ as an example, I want to compute the XRD pattern of its crystal structure. One step is to enumerate all miller indices within a limited sphere as follows:
$$\frac{1}{d_{hkl}}<\frac{2}{\lambda}$$
where, $d_{hkl}$ is the distance between the aligned plane; with $h, k, l$ are the miller indices. $\lambda$ is the X-ray wave length.

Would anyone please tell me how to enumerate all miller indices in the unit cell in the above step or is there any online source to list all miller indices?

Comment: Miller indices are triples of integers selecting the direction of lattice planes in a Bravais lattice. These indices *are not* in a unit cell. So, your question is not clear

Comment: @GiogioP Thank you for the reply. I modified my question with more details. Would you please give me more suggestions?

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Thank you for the reply. I modified my question with more details. Would you please give me more suggestions?

Comment: You'd need to check all triplets of integer numbers up to a certain limit. But if you just want to calculate a powder diffraction pattern, there are programs that can do it: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/142/how-to-calculate-diffraction-pattern-from-a-model-of-unit-cell

Comment: @marcin Thank you for the suggestion. To check all triplets, a maximum integer number must be set for the checking loop of all $h$, $k$, $l$ indices. What maximum integer number should be set up or how to choose the maximum integer number for the checking loop?

Comment: |h| < *a* / d_min, etc. where *a*, *b*, *c* are the unit cell lengths, and I think d_min=λ/2.

Comment: @marcin Thank you very much for the suggestion. Can I ask one more question? I suppose the planes with miller indices ($h=-7$, $k=-7$, $l=-6$) and ($h=-7$, $k=-7$, $l=6$) should have the same structure factor as the sum of atomic scattering factor. Am I correct or not?

Comment: In NaCl (-7 -7 -6) and (-7 -7 6) are the same, but in general they don't need to be. They are equivalent if the space group has symmetry operation x,y,-z.